# EventTrigger in XAML when a property changes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged, eventtrigger

I have this code (it's working, so far);

```
<Image Name="img_person" Tag="{Binding Path=MyProperty1, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0">
  <Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="img_person" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
            By="64"
            Duration="0:0:0.8"
            AutoReverse="False" />
       </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
 </Image.Triggers>
```

I'd like to change this line;

```
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
```

To something like this;

```
    <EventTrigger ThisParticularPropertyHasChanged="MyProperty1">
```

I want to do this as I'll have several storyboards, each to be started when a particular property changes. With 1 property I've been binding it to the image's Tag property, but now that I have several to do (roughly 8) I'm not sure how to go about this.

The class implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

thanks.

SOLUTION, thanks to sa_ddam213;

```
    <Style x:Key="PersonImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UI_DirectionOfMovement}" Value="South">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" By="64" Duration="0:0:0.8" AutoReverse="False" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UI_DirectionOfMovement}" Value="East">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" By="64" Duration="0:0:0.8" AutoReverse="False" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I think your looking for `DataTrigger`, not `EventTrigger`